# Mysql apache2 - phpmyadmin import error (php 7.2)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

I just installed virtual hosts on Apache2 running PHP 7.2 and PhpMyAdmin and now i'm trying to import database from old server. When i click on import on PhpMyAdmin i'm getting this error.

Could someone help me solve this.

```
 Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551 
count (): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable 

Backtrace

./libraries/display_export.lib.php#381: PMA_pluginGetOptions ( 
string 'Export', 
array, 
) 
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#883: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat (array) 
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#1099: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions ( 
string 'server', 
string '', 
string '',
string '<div> <a href="#" onclick="setSelectOptions(\'dump\', \' db_select[]\', true); return false;"> Select All </a> / <a href = "#" onclick = "setSelectOptions (\ 'dump \', \ 'db_select [] \', false); return false;"> Unfair all </a> <br /> <select name = "db_select []" id = "db_select" size = "10" multiple = "multiple"> <option value = "phpmyadmin" selected = "selected"> phpmyadmin </ option> </ select> </ div> ", 
integer 0, 
array 
integer 0 , 
) 
./server_export.php#47: PMA_getExportDisplay ( 
string 'server', 
string '', 
string '',
string '', 
integer 0, 
integer 0,
string '<div> <a href="#" onclick="setSelectOptions(\'dump\', \' db_select[]\', true); return false;"> Select All </a> / <a href = "#" onclick = "setSelectOptions (\ 'dump \', \ 'db_select [] \', false); return false;"> Unfair all </a> <br /> <select name = "db_select []" id = "db_select" size = "10" multiple = "multiple"> <option value = "phpmyadmin" selected = "selected"> phpmyadmin </ option> </ select> </ div> '
```

Comment: Version  of PMA?

Comment: What version of `phpMyAdmin` are you using

Comment: PMA Version is 4.6.6deb5 @JonStirling

Comment: phpMyAdmin version is 4.6.6deb5 @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then I would start by upgrading `phpMyAdmin` as it is not on V4.8.3 at least

Comment: Yeah, that version is over 18 months old, so start there.

Comment: Thanks! :) I manually updated the version and changed the config and now there is no error. Thanks for your fast response and great direction regarding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the following solve my same problem absolutely (import/export and so on):

https://medium.com/@chaloemphonthipkasorn/%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89-bug-phpmyadmin-php7-2-ubuntu-16-04-92b287090b01

so... under ubuntu 18.04, mysql, php7.2: Terminal:

sudo gedit /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php

Find the following line(ctrl+f):

if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {

it was on line #551 for me

and change for following:

if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {

ctrl+s for save the changes

and in terminal: ctrl+c for get back promt...

and: sudo systemctl restart apache2

"I think in new php version.It can’t use count() or sizeof() with un array type. Force parameter to array is easy way to solve this bug,..."

Thanks for the original author for the problem solving! I try to share it!

Answer (score -1):

Open `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php` 
(e.g: `sudo subl /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php`)

Go to line 551,

replace

`if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {`

with

`if ($options != null && (is_array($options) || $options instanceof Countable) && count($options) > 0) {`

Worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: No. One should never ever edit files in `/usr/share` as they get replaced when updating packages, and one should never ever edit files coming from an installed application